# In iPad, how to build a MIME attachment from user drawing view/jpg so it can be upload via SOAP web service

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, soap, mime

I need to upload an user signature on ipad to server by SOAP web service.  The signature will be a MIME attachment for the web service.

Need help to see how can the `UIView` or jpg on iOS can be converted to binary data MIME format so I can put it as part of the web service.  Also, how the `NSURLConnection` can handle the binary data attachment. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need JPEG or PNG format data, you can use [UIImageJPEGRepresentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation) or [UIImagePNGRepresentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation) to convert a UIImage to an NSData object. If you need another format, you may be able to use [CGImageDestination](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/Reference/reference.html); a list of accepted UTIs can be obtained from [CGImageDestinationCopyTypeIdentifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageDestinationCopyTypeIdentifiers). If you just need raw pixel data, draw the image to a CGBitmapImageContext and then read out the buffer using [CGBitmapContextGetData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextGetData); [How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics) may help you there.

As far as NSURLConnection, posts are done using an NSData anyway. It's up to you to format the multipart/form-data structure or SOAP XML document correctly into an NSData, but then NSURLConnection will handle it fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `GLPaint` sample code from Apple, which will give you a view for drawing the signature. It works well in my testing (although you'll want to change the brush texture image): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html

Then, as Anomie said, you can use `CGBitmapContextGetData()` to access the drawn image, and `UIImage` can convert that into a JPEG for you.

Use `NSURLRequest` or a third party SOAP library to send the JPEG to the server.